# What mail application is closest to Outlook functionnalities besides default Mail?

Tags: mac, exchange, calendar, email, contacts

I am looking for a application under Mac OS X that would have most of Outlook (Windows) functionnalities, mainly mail (including rules and tagging), calendar, contacts and Echange  2007+ integration (not using pop or imap)...

Anybody got that? I don't want to have to wait for Outlook 2011 which is rumored to arrived... in 2011!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I guess Outlook 2011 will probably the closest one... MS says it's working on it for end of 2010.

Answer (score 1):

There is [Postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com/) that I've used that looks and works really well. But, it is not free.

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look at it. Free doesn't make it to my 'absolute needs' list anyway ;)

Comment: Ok, no native exchange 2007 support, just pop or imap, otherwise it would be close to a dream!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest Entourage for mail and Personnal Information Manager. Support Exchange (We use it here)

http://www.microsoft.com/mac/products/entourage2008/default.mspx#/interacting_entourage/

Also, you can read this:

http://forums.macnn.com/82/applications/312310/mail-vs-entourage/

Comment: Thanks, but Entourage is too heavy to be so far from Windows version of Outlook (when compared to 2007 or 2010...)